# Import existing project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

```
HTTP Status 404 - /finalprojecttutorspointsecond/

type Status report

message /finalprojecttutorspointsecond/

description The requested resource is not available.
```

I have a problem in port 8080 and Spring Tool Suite by default use this port. So I cleared sts workspace and backed up all project. When I install a new Spring Tool Suite instance and import my project the error shows this. How to fix and run again my projects?

Comment: You didn't provide us enough information to fix your issue.

Comment: i have installed a new Spring tool suite and import an existing dynamic web project ....the error is given above